How to see logs older than 12 hours in Azure
I've turned on app logging to stream the logs. The problem's that the streamer is only active in 12 hours (and default timout is 2). Certain issues in our case occur rather rarely, so when a user gets back to me, the time's already passed (and in some cases, the error can't be reproduced due to other circumstances).
We're logging rather extensively and, as long as I sit on my local environment, I can trace virtually anything in the terminal window. Each event, warning, error etc. is logged out including a GUID. This works great.
How can I get to search by a GUID in the logs that are produced while hosting on the server? I've read some blogs but get confused - partly because the GUI in Azure changed recently, partly because I can't see how to access the continuous payload of the logged information as I can locally. Perhaps there's an even better way, which I'm ignorant of, but I tried to follow the MSDN on the subject.


Are you doing logging in the app? For example we have .net apps in App Service that we use Serilog to log to Azure Storage Tables. This gives us more control over use the log levels.

@DogBoy37 Yes, I do the logging using the injected ILogger<WhateverService> instance. I can see the info in the logs when executing locally and checking the terminal. I'd like to see the same content either live in the streaming log or (even better on occasion) in a stored text file. The idea is to look for the GUID that comes into the logs and the GUI to recognize the occurrence of the issue.

The availability of these logs are typically only long enough to allow them to be ingested into a SIEM. Or anywhere else really.

@GregAskew Are you saying that I can't analyze logs older than 12 hours and that there's no way to automatically store those somehow for future reviews? That's problematic because some issues may appear rather infrequently and sporadically, still being a huge impediment on the organization.

That is the expectation of using a logging toolset for long term log capture.

@DogBoy37 I feel slow-minded. Not sure what you mean - please help me understand.

@KonradViltersten Think of it this way. The generic microsoft logging isn't easily flexible. It goes to the log stream. If you want a more granular or controlled logging solution that should be either planned during app design or as a collaboration between app design and the deployment team (whichever framework or logic is used). My personal opinion is log stream is only really useful to test for the first few minutes.

@KonradViltersten   Basically did the app launch as expected without any connectivity or security issues. For having detail information that persists, have a better plan. That is what I am referring to by using an different logging provider. If you are not the app developer, please include them in this conversation.

@DogBoy37 I'm the developer. I'm asking how to resolve it without Serilog because, as far I know, it makes things easier but the actual logging á la contents of the terminal window when executed on my localhost should be tech agnostic.

@KonradViltersten That is the benefit of using something like serilog or a similar package.   In my example, it goes to both the console and Azure Table Storage. Notice:  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],   The "Using" has several dozen options where the log can be written. It is tech agnostic. I have been where you are now. Try a proof of concept app using a logging provider like serilog.

There may be more appropriate solutions for you specific need.
Everything that I've found is that 12 hours is all that streaming logs provides. I may be wrong, but there are other easier solutions than fighting something that isn't intended for longer term troubleshooting.
This is what we do for some of our dotnet apps that are hosted in Azure App Services.
Using the ILogger is the first step, but what is your loggin provider or providers? The default Microsoft provider isn't suitable for our needs. We chose Serilog, because we deploy the same apps many different ways and we can just update an appsettings.json to modify where the log is written.
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose", // "Verbose" Information  Error
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=accountKeyGibberish;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
          "StorageTableName": "someAppName"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Some App Api"
    }
  }

For a simple minimal api api
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger.Information($"Start Some App  args: {args.Length}");

builder.Host.UseSerilog();
.....
.....

All the logs are the tables

If you choose serilog, it has plently of documentation and examples including in SO.
